# How to get the user info by the public key the user sent over ssh?

Tags: linux, github, ssh, pki

When a user connect over SSH with public key, how did Github detect which user it is?

```
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi **Ben**! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

How to implement such a feature, especially consider that the user info is in some database like MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is done using a centralized authorized_keys file along with the command option.  Check out the AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT section of the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd).

Answer (score -1):

User always sends login (`git` in your case).  Public/private key pair is used only to verify user identify.

Comment: This is not true.  everyone can try to log in with the username git @ github.com and it will output whatever github username is actually associated with your public key.